# How to display same table multiple times with Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2011

I have two tables on a report. Across the two tables, I need 8 total columns. The tables have the same data; only the columns shown are different. I need the first table drawn first, and then the next table after that on a new page.

Here's the report structure I would like...

Page 1:

```
Properties Table

Id | Name | etc...
--------------------
1  | Bob  | ...
2  | Matt | ...
3  | John | ...
...
```

After Properties table, on a new page:

```
Relationships Table

Id | Relationships | etc...
-----------------------------
1  | Matt          | ...
2  | Bob           | ...
3  | (NULL)        | ...
...
```

Assuming the data source is the same for both tables (it returns all 8 columns I need), how can I achieve this on the report?

I believe the idea is to use subreports, but I can't find a mechanism to pass in the data from the main report.

Comment: To clarify: 
1.) Your database has two different tables that you care about (not one with 8 columns)?
2.) Each of these two tables has 4 columns
3.) You want to call one table on page and another table on the next page?
4.) "The tables have the same data" I read this to mean they have the same values in the columns, the columns just have different names. But, then in your sample tables the 2nd columns have different values

Comment: @Jackson 1. No I mean my database has only *one view* I am getting data out of. This view contains all data I need for my two tables on the report. 2. Each table on the report has 4 columns. 3. No I want to construct two tables but call the same view. The difference between the two tables is the columns that I choose to display from the view. 4. I meant the tables have the same records, but different columns visible.

Comment: why do you want data from main report to sub report? are you linking tables and data?